# get array Http Client have value but value in component undefined on Angular 9

Tags: angular

get array Http Client have value but value in component undefined on Angular 9

my value is undefined

this is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RequestService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  private address = 'http://localhost:8080/request';

  public getAll<T>(): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(this.address);
  }
}
```

this is my components.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestService } from './request.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-request',
  templateUrl: './table-request.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-request.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TableRequestComponent implements OnInit {
  dataList!: [];
  constructor(private rs: RequestService) {
    this.loadData();
    console.log(this.dataList)//this is console.log
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  loadData() {
    this.rs.getAll().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.dataList = res;
    });
  }
}
```

this is result from console.log
https://i.stack.imgur.com/51YPh.png

Comment: Instead of calling loadData() method in constructor, try calling it in oninit().

Comment: The `dataList` variable is assigned asynchronously and you **cannot** access it synchronously. Any statements that directly depend on it should be inside the subscription. In other words, subscribe to the `getAll()` observable where it's response is required.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `console.log` before the API call is returned, try to change it to:

```
loadData() {
  this.rs.getAll().subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.dataList = res;
    console.log(this.dataList);
  });
}
```

Comment: It work. But value in dataList it still undefined. I don’t know how to fix it

Comment: What is datalist! Shouldn't it be data list?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export class TableRequestComponent implements OnInit {
  dataList: [];
  constructor(private rs: RequestService) {        
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData();        
  }
  loadData() {
    this.rs.getAll().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.dataList = res;
      console.log(this.dataList)//this is console.log
    });
  }
}
```

And bind your "dataList" to your display (like a table). You can read more about asynchronous call to know why you cannot get "datatList" value outside the "subscribe".